# Going to US on ESTA before going Central America and then back to US for flight home all within 90 days. This all good?

Tags: visas, usa, esta

Any help much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will not be a problem.

Since you will visit Central America you qualify for a new VWP (Visa Waiver Program) period when you re-enter the US. If you do that it's irrelevant whether it happens more or less than 90 days from your first entry.

If you enter the second time from Mexico, Canada or the Caribbean they may assume you can enter on the same VWP. This will actually not be a problem either since you will leave less then 90 days before your first entry.

Either way you will not have a problem.

Comment: Actually, under the statute, there is discretion only if the traveler doesn't leave "contiguous territory" and "adjacent islands" (Canada, Mexico, Caribbean).  In that case, the officer *can* readmit them for the duration of the original period of admission, or they can give them a new one.  If they travel beyond Canada, Mexico, and the Caribbean, the officer must give them a new period of admission.  At least, that's what the law says.  Whether it works that way in practice, I am less certain.

Comment: I've only ever done this when entering from Canada so they may have assumed I didn't leave the contiguous territory.

Comment: Indeed, that seems likely.